# Android how to notify user is no connectivity

Tags: android

I have a background service running which is getting me data. Before getting data, I am checking for connectivity. If there is no WI-Fi or cellular coverage, how should I notify user?

The first thing crossed my mind is POP UP A DIALOG. But's throwing error. I prefer not to have status bar notification. I would like it to be more on your face kind of a thing. What are my options ?

Comment: How do I do that ? I am running a separate thread to get data. If I add a Toast or Dialog it's throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd use a [Notification in the status bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). And I'd put a PendingIntent in the notification to let the user retry the operation once they have connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

If your service does something very important and you think user should know when connectivity is lost, then the only solution that is acceptable (according to guidelines) is to post notification to notification bar.

You should not start any Activities or Dialogs from your service. To shortly explain why, imagine user has 10 such services. If every service would start Activity or Dialog it would be a mess when connectivity is lost, and would definitely drive user mad. Another scenario to consider is when connectivity is lost and re-acquired every second. Again, it would make device almost unusable if at least one service decides it must show user activity or dialog.

In most cases you shouldn't even post notifications when connectivity is lost. User already has some feedback in notification bar: Wi-Fi icon and 3G/4G/etc icons. So adding another icon would clutter notification bar with duplicated info.

Comment: OK. If I go with notification, can I clear that notification programatically when it's connected. I don't want it to sit there for a while and user will not know "when was this" ...

Comment: Yes, you can. Read this for more details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html